# Does pycparser supports user defined types?

Tags: python, c, parsing, pycparser

Does pycparser supports user defined types? I want to get list of functions with user defined type as return type from *.C file.

Answer (score 2):

Sure it does. You just want to write a visitor for `FuncDef` nodes.

The `FuncDef` contains a `Decl`, whose type child is a `FuncDecl`.
This `FuncDecl` has the return type as its type child.

The return type is either a `TypeDecl`, in which case the type identifier
is its type child, or it's a `PtrDecl`, in which case its type child is the `TypeDecl`, whose type child is the type identifier.

Got that? Heres an example `FuncDef` visitor that prints the name and return type of every function:

```
class FuncDefVisitor(c_ast.NodeVisitor):
"""
A simple visitor for FuncDef nodes that prints the names and
return types of definitions.
"""
def visit_FuncDef(self, node):
    return_type = node.decl.type.type
    if type(return_type) == c_ast.TypeDecl:
        identifier = return_type.type
    else: # type(return_type) == c_ast.PtrDecl
        identifier = return_type.type.type
    print("{}: {}".format(node.decl.name, identifier.names))
```

Here's the output when parsing the hash.c example file in the cparser distribution:

```
hash_func: ['unsigned', 'int']
HashCreate: ['ReturnCode']
HashInsert: ['ReturnCode']
HashFind: ['Entry']
HashRemove: ['ReturnCode']
HashPrint: ['void']
HashDestroy: ['void']
```

Now you just need to filter out the built-in types, or filter for the UDTs you're interested in.